# Ugly PDF output when there are multiple lines in a list-table cell

Tags: pdf, latex, python-sphinx

I'm trying to generate a table with multi-line cell with Sphinx and LaTeX.

```
.. list-table:: Detail of GPIO_SET Register
   :widths: 15 15 15 15 40
   :header-rows: 1

   * - Name
     - Bit
     - Access
     - Reset
     - Description
   * - gpio_set
     - [31:0]
     - RV/W
     - 32'h0
     - | Read: This is the first line.
       | Write: This is the second line.
```

It really works in the preview html.

[image: html list-table with multi-line cell]

And the pdf looks good if there is only one-line (without using | to make a text block) too.

[image: pdf list-table with single-line cell]

But the pdf looks ugly if the cell contains multi-line text block with '|'. there are too much spaces in the cell. If the table has more rows, it even doesn't respect the paper size and got broken table.

[image: pdf list-table with multi-line cell]

Questions:

1. Is there a way to avoid this issue with multi-line list-table cell while generating latexpdf?
2. Is there another way to generate beautiful multi-line cell table? Will it work using normal table?
   I hope the list-table will work, because it's easy to generate using script.

Answer (score 1):

If using a different builder is an option, you can try [rinohtype](http://www.mos6581.org/rinohtype/master/quickstart.html#sphinx-builder)*. The default stylesheet renders the table like this:
[image: table as rendered by rinohtype]

By creating a [custom style sheet](http://www.mos6581.org/rinohtype/master/basicstyling.html), you can further tweak many aspects of the output to your liking, such as the [vertical alignment](http://www.mos6581.org/rinohtype/master/style/rinoh.table.TableCellStyle.html#rinoh.table.TableCellStyle.vertical_align) of table cell contents and item margins.

* Full disclosure: I am rinohtype's author.